# Disable 1 time firing double click event from Multiple Choice Lookup column using jQuery/javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, lookup-column

I have a multiple choice column of potential attendees that are to be enrolled in a course. After the number of available spots is filled, I disable the column along with the "Add" button, yet one problem remains.

When I open the page, the first option appears to be selected. If I double-click on the selection area, that first option, the potential attendee is put on the attendee's list to the right. I have searched this topic quite a bit and no solution worked so far.

Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621652/how-to-prevent-a-double-click-using-jquery

Comment: All of them :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with an `.on( "click", function( event )` put on the left side selection list.

Also added a variable that would start at `0` and `++` at each click event on that element.

When `var = 1` I pop up an alert to the user not to click there again. The 2nd time, I use `location.reload();`

If there is a more elegant method, please let me know.